# Using Ruby to access ODATA service

Tags: ruby, excel, odata

**Background**:

Trying to find and use a library in Ruby which will enable access to an OData feed from MS Project Online.  The purpose is to be able to read the information about what projects and resources have been stored in the Project management system.

**Problem**:

Have located two main Ruby gems for ODATA access

1. Ruby-Odata:   [OData Client Library](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_odata)
2. Odata: [OData](https://rubygems.org/gems/odata)

The service which is trying to be accessed is via HTTPS; typically like https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Projects  This will also have a username and password due to it being an authenticated service.  But the problem is that the authentication fails, although when using this same service via an Excel data connection I'm able to access the list of Projects

**Tests**:

The code attempt, using Odata,  looks like:

```
# https://github.com/visoft/ruby_odata

require 'ruby_odata'

svc = OData::Service.new "https://blogfodder.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Projects/",{:username => "blah", :password => "xxxxxx"}

svc.Projects
```

Running this code produces the following error:

```
/Users/grantsayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@odata/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:74:in `return!': 403 Forbidden (RestClient::Forbidden)
```

This of course shows that authentication is a problem. The issue is that I'm able to execute this connection via Excel, and also in a web browser, just not over the API.

The alternative library (Odata) whilst not producing an authentication error ends up with no data being returned.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Note - used Curl to evaluate the handshake via 'curl https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Projects -v ---ntlm --negotiate -u user:password  This gives an interesting error message:  "X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically."  Looks like it's a Sharepoint access issue at this stage.

Comment: Discovered that Sharepoint uses 'Claims Based Authentication'; basically means there is an intermediate step which the simple NTLM Odata steps fail on.  Background on accessing Sharepoint is at http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/